# List the properties of a class in VBA 2003

Tags: excel, vba, oop, properties

I've searched all over to see if there is an easy answer to this question, but there doesn't seem to be...

I'm using Excel VBA 2003 (yes, I know it's out-of date, but I can't change this), and all I want to do is list the names and values of all the readable properties in a given custom class.

I'd like to do something like this:

**Class definition (for class entitled cFooBar)**

```
Option Explicit

Private pFoo As String
Private pBar As String

Public Property Get Foo() As String
Foo=pFoo
End Property

Public Property Get Bar() As String
Bar=pBar
End Property
```

**Calling code**

```
Dim myFooBar as cFooBar, P as Property
myFooBar=new cFooBar
For Each P in myFooBar.Properties
Debug.Print P.Name, P.Value
Next
```

Of course, this doesn't work because there doesn't seem to be a "Properties" collection member for custom classes (or at least not one that you can get at), and there isn't a "Property" type either.

Does anybody know a way around this?

TIA,

Campbell

Comment: What you're describing is reflection which is not well established in VBA, but I saw this article that seems to allow you to do something similar to what you're describing... This is untested - I just saw it: http://www.amolpandey.com/2012/08/05/dynamic-vba-properties-getset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As John mentions above, reflection is not supported in VBA. Here is a hack that I have used before. Basically you can create a Collection or Dictionary object to store your "properties" by name.

```
Option Explicit

Private pProperties As Object

Public Property Get Properties() As Object
    Set Properties=pProperties
End Property

Public Property Let Properties(p as Object) 
    Set pProperties = p
End Property


Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pProperties = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Add/instantiate your properties here
    pProperties("foo") = "this is foo"
    pProperties("bar") = "this is bar"


End Sub
```

Calling code

```
Dim myFooBar As New cFooBar, P As Variant

For Each P In myFooBar.Properties.Keys()
    Debug.Print P, myFooBar.Properties(P)
Next
```

Comment: Just wondering when you can have a public Scripting.Dictionary object, why you need any class module? You can assign whatever property to that with categories and groups.

Comment: @Mahhdy I'm not sure I understand your question. the original problem here pertains to a custom object (class module). whether a class module is necessary is irrelevant (and dependent on the situation). here, I assume it's necessary. there are things you can do with classes that you simply cannot do with module or procedure scopedl variables, such as instantiation. they're also useful for modeling complex data structures, etc.

Comment: I know the class module is an essential part of programming.  I meant just for that purpose of having the list of properties and their respective value.

Comment: @Mahhdy because you want the properties dictionary to represent the properties of a particular *instance*. If all you need is to list the property *names*, and those are all shared across all instances, then you don't need to attach it to an instance of the class. But that doesn't seem like a normal use-case IMO.