# Set a reference to an Enum

Tags: vba, excel

I have an application that consists of multiple sheets, each containing similar data in a grid layout.

[image: Sheet1]

```
Enum eSht1
    FName = 1
    LName = 2
    Data1 = 3
    Data2 = 4
End Enum
```

The issue is to extract data at the intersection of a row/column.  To get the column, a macro searches row 1 for the desired number corresponding the desired item.  Eg, for LName the macro would search for `2` and return column `B`.

These numbers are subject to change, both in value & position – I have no control over this, the client is the “interface” designer, my job is to make the VBA code work.  So to facilitate any changes, these numbers are contained in an Enum.  So in this example, the macro would search for `eSht1.LName`.

This has worked well in the past, with one data sheet per workbook, but now we’re rolling all these sheets into a single workbook.  As all these tables have similar data, it would be nice to use the same procedures throughout.

[image]

```
Enum eSht2
    Index = 10
    FName = 20
    LName = 30
    Data2 = 40
End Enum
```

The problem is to reference the various Enums from a single macro.  So for instance, to extract LName from sheet1, the macro would search with `eSht1.LName`.  To get LName from sheet2, the same macro would search with `eSht2.LName`.

This is a dummied down example, there are 20+ sheets, and a substantial number of macros scattered throughout the project that reference these Enums.
Is this possible, or do I need to have separate macros for each sheet?   Or try a totally different approach?

Comment: Don't you think that this approach is an Overkill? In Excel, by default, Col A = 1, Column B = 2 and so on. You can directly use column numbers with sheet names to access a particular column/cell

Comment: To find out, say, what column number `AA` is, simply put this formula in cell `AA1`, `=Column(AA2)`

Comment: Yes, in my examples it may seem like overkill, but in actual fact these tables can appear anywhere on the sheet, and usually don't start at column A, if I'm understanding your comment.  Also, as I indicated, these columns can be moved around quite frequently, the only `constant` are the numbers in row 1.  Eg, in the 2nd sheet, Fname is in column J and the number is 20.  At a later date Fname may be placed in column M, for example, and M1 would have the value 20.  So rather than remembering arbitrary numbers, enum seems to make more sense.

Comment: As these numbers may also get changed from time to time, Enum makes maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: `So rather than remembering arbitrary numbers, enum seems to make more sense.` Do you know that you can find the column number using a simple `.Find`?

Comment: Let's say we want to find the column number which has `Fname` somewhere in row 2 of sheet2. Then you can use `Set aCell = Sheet2.Row(2)Find(What:="Fname", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)` and then `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then Msgbox aCell.Column`

Comment: @Siddharth – I appreciate the interest you’ve taken in this, thanks.  And yes, I totally understand what you’re suggesting, it would appear to be the most logical, straightforward way - in fact that was our initial approach.  This application is a large one, and has been in development for some time now (over a year), with other people working on the interface portion.  So things tend to get altered over time, heading’s text being one of them, which would then “break” the application.  It became apparent that the only reliable constants were the numbers.

Comment: It’s starting to look like we may need to find another way.

Comment: The reason why I am giving you simpler alternatives is because of your last statement in your question "Or try a totally different approach?"

Comment: `To get the column, a macro searches row 1 for the desired number corresponding the desired item. Eg, for LName the macro would search for 2 and return column B.` Here also you are searching for the column number based on the name? But in your 2nd last comment you mentioned that the names may change. Then how would you cope?

Comment: @Siddharth - Ah, I see I clouded the issue with my choice of values.  I've edited my post, and now you can see that the enum element names do not match the heading names, so they can change without affecting anything.  We're talking 50+ headings - without assigning the values to variables, maintenance becomes a nightmare.  And with Enums you have the advantage of IntelliSense.   I'll have a look at J-V's post, but I'm thinking of going with 2 arrays - not as good as enums, but will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siddharth Rout brings up valid points in the comments, you might be better off sticking with just the names instead of keeping track of two different values.

---

*However*, if you are feeling adventurous, you could create a `Class Module` to help deal with these value pairs. This is helpful if the goal is to be able to use something similar to `CallByName` on `Enum`.

As a result you could do something along the lines of:

`eSht1.Properties("FName") ' Returns 1`

How is that any better than writing `eSht1.FName`? With a class you can access the values with a *variable*. This makes iterating over multiple properties or objects very simple.

---

For example, consider having the following `CEnum` Class Module modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066959/3721894):

```
Option Explicit

Private pProperties As Object

Public Property Get Properties() As Object
  Set Properties = pProperties
End Property

Public Property Let Properties(p As Object)
  Set pProperties = p
End Property

Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set pProperties = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  'Add/instantiate your properties here
  pProperties("Index") = 0
  pProperties("FName") = 0
  pProperties("LName") = 0
  pProperties("Data1") = 0
  pProperties("Data2") = 0
End Sub
```

With this class we can then get properties from any or all `CEnum` objects rather easily.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestCEnums()

  ' You can set a CEnum to a variable and instantiate the "properties"
  Dim e1 As New CEnum
  With e1
    .Properties("Index") = 1
    .Properties("Data1") = 10
  End With

  ' If you'd prefer to have all of the CEnums in a collection, it might be
  ' better to add them via a function
  Dim enums As New Collection
  AddEnum "e2", enums, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
  AddEnum "e3", enums, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
  AddEnum "e4", enums, 99, 88, 77, 66, 55

  ' Having everything under the dictionary object makes it trivial to get all
  ' properties from any (or every) CEnum object
  Debug.Print "All properties from e1:"
  Dim p As Variant
  For Each p In e1.Properties.Keys()
    Debug.Print p, e1.Properties(p)
  Next

  enums.Add e1, "e1", "e2" ' Add e1 to the collection

  ' You can also get only a specific property from all CEnums in a collection
  Debug.Print vbCrLf & "The Index property from all CEnums:"
  Dim e As CEnum
  For Each e In enums
    Debug.Print e.Properties("Index")
  Next

End Sub
```

This produces the following output:

```
All properties from e1:
Index          1 
FName          0 
LName          0 
Data1          10 
Data2          0 

The Index property from all CEnums:
 1 
 11 
 22 
 99
```

---

Here's the `AddEnum` function for this example:

```
' Adds a new CEnum to a collection
Private Function AddEnum( _
                          key As String, _
                          enums As Collection, _
                          myIndex As Long, _
                          myFName As Long, _
                          myLName As Long, _
                          myData1 As Long, _
                          myData2 As Long _
                        )

  Dim tempEnum As New CEnum
  With tempEnum
    .Properties("Index") = myIndex
    .Properties("FName") = myFName
    .Properties("LName") = myLName
    .Properties("Data1") = myData1
    .Properties("Data2") = myData2
  End With

  enums.Add tempEnum, key
  Set tempEnum = Nothing

End Function
```

---

**EDIT**

You aren't limited to just using the hack "properties" in the actual `Properties` property object. *(Not at all confusing!)* If each `CEnum` is linked to a specific worksheet, for example, you could add a `Sheet` property with its own `Get` and `Let` block. This would let you add conditional checks to your loops.

```
  ' SNIP
  For Each e In enums
    If e.Sheet = someSheet Then
      ' Do something
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: J_V, thanks for this – I haven’t had a chance to look at this in detail, but it does seem point the way to a few alternate possibilities.  I’ll mark your post as answered because of the idea.  I’m under the gun to get this working, so for the moment I’m going to go with double arrays.  I will lose the intellisense of the enums, unfortunately, but I guess I can live with that for now.  Once I’m caught up, I’ll come back and re-examine your solution.