# Number of members in VBA class

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a VBA class with few member variables defined as

```
Public A as String
Public B as Variant
.
.
.
Public N as Integer
```

Is there any simple way to find out total how many members are declared in class?

Comment: VBA isn't strong on reflection, so I am not optimistic that there is an easy answer to this. There are ways of getting programmatic access to the actual code in the code modules, so there probably is a round-about way of achieving this by inspecting the actual code in the class module

Comment: No.  If this is important for you then define a single variable as a collection, then use an enumeration to index into the collection.

Comment: see for an example to enumerate here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066959/8537807

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will just count them for the time being before I change my code to make collection or anything else.

Comment: you could copy the list into an excel worksheet assuming there is only one declaration per line. You'd know by how many rows there are...

Comment: MZTools provides statistics on your code including Methods and Properties in a Module. Also, I think Rob Bovey's Code Documentor may help as well